# Difference between LINQ FirstOrDefault vs. Where(...).FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

What difference between

```
FirstOrDefault(someField => someField.Name.Equals(settings.Text))
```

and

```
Where(someField => someField.Name.Equals(settings.Text)).FirstOrDefault()
```

?

As far as I understand in both cases Linq will run till the first occurence that suits the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we are talking about Linq to Objects, then there is one notable difference. Second statement

```
Where(someField => someField.Name.Equals(settings.Text)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Will create `WhereEnumerableIterator` internally, and then it will start enumeration and take first item:

```
// argument checks and collection optimizations removed
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
     this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
     // it enumerates source and returns items which match predicate
     return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
}

public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())        
            return enumerator.Current;        
    }

    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

But first statement will just take first item from source which matches predicate without creating additional enumerator:

```
// argument checks removed
public static TSource First<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{    
    foreach (TSource local in source)
    {
        if (predicate(local))        
            return local;        
    }

    throw Error.NoMatch();
}
```

So, first one is better in terms of performance:

```
FirstOrDefault(someField => someField.Name.Equals(settings.Text))
```

Answer (score 9):

They result of both statements is the same. You can think of the first one as a shorter version of the second one.

The `FirstOrDefault` method has [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) taking in a second parameter, a `Func<TSource, bool>` which is the same predicate you are defining in your `Where` statement.

Comment: @wudzik Really? I would guess properly optimized SQL would look the same.

Comment: In older version of entity framework the first option will not work, and the second will, and I don't know why. but I faced with it in some project.